# I'm trying to deduplicate weblinks scraped using Python & BeautifulSoup but it's not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website in Python, I got the links to print but in trying to make them a set to deduplicate, there are still duplicates.  Anyone have any advice on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: So I tried what John suggested but my csv output is a cascading list of links across the excel sheet, it's crazy...I'll post the changes below this original code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r   = requests.get(page)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
mylink = soup.find_all('a')
print ('The number of links to start with are: ', len(mylink) )    
#output = The number of links to start with are: 254
import csv
with open('census_links.csv', 'w', newline='') as f: 
weblinks = str(mylink)
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ' ', lineterminator = '\r')
for link in mylink:
    hrefs = str(link.get('href'))
    if hrefs.startswith("None"):
        ''
    elif hrefs.startswith('http'):
        MySet = set()
        MySet.add(hrefs)
    elif hrefs.startswith('#'):
        ''
    elif hrefs.startswith(' '):
        ''
    print(set(MySet))
    file.write(str(MySet)+'\n')
    file.close


#Edited code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r   = requests.get(page)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
mylink = soup.find_all('a')
print ('The number of links to start with are: ', len(mylink))
# The number of links to start with are:  254
import csv
with open('census_links.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    weblinks = str(mylink)
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',', lineterminator = '\r')
    MySet = set()
for link in mylink:
    hrefs = str(link.get('href'))
    if hrefs.startswith("None"):
        continue
    elif hrefs.startswith('#'):
        continue
    elif hrefs.startswith(' '):
        continue
    elif hrefs.startswith('http'):
        MySet.add(hrefs)
        file.write(str(MySet)+'\n')
        file.close
print(str(MySet) +'\n')
```

Comment: Can you give an example of both actual and desired input/output pairs?

Comment: There are a couple hundred links produced but duplicates are obvious...here are the first few lines of output. set()
set()
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/topics/population/age-and-sex.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/businessandeconomy'}

Comment: The output I need would contain the links from the page without any duplicate links.

Comment: Can you also fix the indentation of your code, I might see some errors, but it is hard to tell.

Comment: If the link starts with `http`, you're creating a _new_ empty set, which discards the previous contents.  But you're _printing_ each set at the bottom of the loop, so that output _appears_ to have duplicates.

Comment: John, instead of empty set, what should I put in the parentheses? Should it be 'weblinks'? I am a total beginner.  Thanks

Comment: Initialize `MySet()` before the loop, and wait to print it until after the loop is finished.

Comment: It came out weird...here's some of the output. set()
set()
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/topics/population/age-and-sex.html', 'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}
{'https://www.census.gov/topics/population/age-and-sex.html', 'https://www.census.gov/businessandeconomy', 'https://www.census.gov/en.html'}

Comment: You're still printing each time inside the loop.  Don't do that.

Comment: Will you please show me an example?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get unique links, you want to check if the link is in `MySet` with `hrefs not in MySet`.

for simple operation you don't need `csv`, to write in single row

```
"\n".join(MySet)
```

and to write single column

```
",".join(MySet)
```

```python
MySet = set()
for link in mylink:
    hrefs = link.get('href')
    if not hrefs or hrefs.startswith('#'):
        continue
    # normalize link
    if hrefs.startswith('/'):
      hrefs = 'https://www.census.gov' + hrefs

    # check if link already in MySet
    if hrefs not in MySet: 
        MySet.add(hrefs)

with open('census_links.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(MySet))

print("\n".join(MySet))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, it worked perfectly, thank you so much! 

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the set before the loop, and wait to print it until after the loop is done.

```
MySet = set()
...
for link in mylink:
    hrefs = str(link.get('href'))
    ...
    if hrefs.startswith('http'):
        MySet.add(hrefs)
    ...
print(MySet)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I still cant get it to work right.  I added the edited code above if you have a chance to look.  I appreciate it. 

Comment: Move the `file.write()` to also be outside the loop.

Comment: Also, you probably want to use the `writer` object to write to the csv, instead of calling plain `file.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

same code part to get content.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
r   = requests.get(page)
raw_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
mylink = soup.find_all('a')
print ('The number of links to start with are: ', len(mylink) )    
#output = The number of links to start with are: 254
```

use pandas to get the unique url which starts with `http`.

```
import pandas as pd

obj = pd.Series(mylink)
obj_link = obj.map(lambda x: x.get('href')).drop_duplicates().dropna()
cond = obj_link.str.startswith('http')
dfn = obj_link.loc[cond].to_frame()

dfn.shape # (93, 1)
dfn.to_csv('census_links.csv', index=False, header=False)
```